# One light with two switches, changed one to dimmer, blew fuse

Tags: switch, led, light

I have a kitchen light that had two different switches on either side of the kitchen. I replaced the light with a dimmable LED mount and changed one switch to a LED comparable dimmer which works great but when I flip the switch on the other wall the fuse blows. 
Do I need to get a similar dimmer for the other switch too?
Why is that happening, Any suggestions?

Comment: We'll need you to post photos or a diagram. As it is, we can only guess at what's wrong, which is no way to solve a problem. Welcome to DIYSE.

Comment: One LED compatible dimmer, (virtually all of which are **3-way switch** functional) is all you need if wired correctly. Odds are excellent that something is not wired correctly, so we need to know how you've wired it to offer any more hope of solving the problem.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Feel free to [edit] in the pictures (the little mountain icon above the text edit box is what you click to add images), then while you're waiting for a response, take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn how to get the best out of the site.

Comment: Also, when you say "blew fuse", is this actually going to a fuse box, or did you really mean that it tripped a circuit breaker?